# Email problems on ipad

Tags: ipad

I received an email in my inbox on my ipad from somebody I know and it said what's app message press play. When I pressed play it went to a yahoo page and was like a yahoo mail login and I put my email password in. Shortly afterwards I received over 100 emails daemon mailer unable to deliver. I deleted them and changed my yahoo email password but I am now concerned that there may be a virus on my ipad. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as **Phishing** or Social Engineering.

You were tricked into giving away your login details, by being directed to a site that looked familiar, but which wasn't actually the legitimate site you thought it was.

You were correct to immediately change your password. In most situations this is sufficient to prevent further access by the phishers.  They don't really want to go to any effort to spread their spam, fooling you once would be enough; trying to hack you after you changed the password would be too much like hard work.

It is very unlikely that any malware is on your iPad - but it may 'remember' the fake site in your history, so be careful when going to the legitimate site that you do indeed have the right one.

If you normally use password auto-fill on your iPad, then one very good sign of a fake site is that the iPad will **not** offer to auto-fill. As far as it's concerned it's not the same site. It is far more likely to notice the difference between `yahoo.com` & `yalhoo.com` etc than a human.

See Jaime Santa Cruz's answer for further practical advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Yahoo! account preferences or settings for redirects, filters, changes on the security questions, secondary addresses that could have been modified.

An iPad virus is not very probable but [not impossible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18128/is-it-possible-for-an-ipad-or-any-ios-product-to-get-a-virus), especially if your iPad is jailbroken.

1. [Don't click on emails' links](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/what-malicious-things-can-happen-when-clicking-on-links-in-email)
2. If you really want to click on them; tap and keep pressed the link so it will show you the [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator). This is not really totally fool proof, as described in the link on point 1.
3. Check the URL: it should relate to what you're supposed to be
   clicking on. In this case, it should have something to do with
   WhatsApp, so one would expect *.whatsapp.com at the beggining of the URL. If
   it asked you for your Yahoo! credentials, https://*.yahoo.com should
   be on that URL, and an 's' should probably be there after the http
   indicating it is a secure site.
4. If you already clicked on the link, repeat step 3. The URL is written on the top of your [browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser).
5. If you have any doubt, close the page, and do not enter your credentials.
6. If you do not understand any of this instructions, go to step 1.

What probably happened is that a bot used your Yahoo! account to send spam and lot of fake whatsapp messages to everyone on your contact list after it obtained the credentials you gave it on the fake Yahoo! login page. All of the contacts that had invalid email addresses gave back a typical [bounce message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message) issued by the Mailer-Daemon.